# jQuery Sortable + Draggable any where in the container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to make one page on which a user can sort the items in the UL, in addition user is also allowed to drag and drop it any where else in the container.

But if user drops it on other element it reverts back to it's position. I tried to find solution on the web, but did not get any.

Is there any way to do this ? If yes can some one please help, if one can show example that would be useful.

Than You...

Answer (score 0):

Checkout,
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

and

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Hope this helps.